# Using raycast how to make player run between two colliders without colliding in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, collision-detection, raycasting, unityscript

I am trying to let the player run on a path between two colliders on either sides using the accelerometer. I want my player to come back to the center after colliding with the sidewalls when I tilt the device.

I have tried using Raycast, but I am not getting it.

Comment: Consider marking your questions as answered when answers have helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use Raycasting when you try to detect a collision. You have the [`OnCollisionEnter()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and the [`OnTriggerEnter()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) methods. These detect when you collide with an other object. When that happens, you can set the position of your Player-object.

Comment: thank you for helping.. with trigger enter how can i make the collider push my player in opposite direction ?? iam not using rigidbody for my player..

Comment: How are you moving your player, codewise?